# Why email clients prepend `Re:` to subject line?

Tags: email

I wonder why most email clients prepend `Re:` to the subject if the mail is a
response.

When responding, the mail client generates an `In-Reply-To:` header which
clearly states that this message is a response. This enables mail user agents
to display the mails in the correct thread (together with the `References:`
header). So technically the `Re:` does not add any information.

The disadvantages are:

- The `Re:` string needs to be adjusted to the language (`Sv:`, `Odp:`, `Vs:`, etc.) which makes it very hard to configure the mail client properly.
- It adds visual clutter to the subject line.
- It can lead to subject lines like this: `Re: Re: Sv: Odp: Re: This is the subject`

Why is this common practice and what are the advantages?

Comment: That's off-topic here. The in-reply-to and references headers are optional, and different mailers have different ways to thread emails, with Microsoft having been know to use its own silly specific way.

Comment: I assume the use of `Re:` predates the widespread use of Microsofts mail clients.

Comment: The all too common practice of localizing the `Re:` prefix is actually an error and a violation of the RFC. Arguably the spec can be considered broken, but that does not mean it's okay to violate it.

Comment: @tripleee Are you sure? “MAY start with the string "Re:"” does not imply “May not start with anything else than "Re"”. Which paragraph forbids the localisation of `Re:`?

Answer (score 5):

The practice originated with paper mails, not emails. In computer terms it's ancient; it's been defined in the RFCs for email messages since at least RFC822. (Now I think of it, it's probably defined in the standards for UUCP and NNTP messages too.)

The current standard for message formats is [RFC 5322](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt), which in appendix A.2. 
states `When sending replies, the Subject field is often retained, though prepended with "Re: " as described in section 3.6.5.`

It's interesting to note that the "Re" does **not** mean "reply", but "reference", "regarding", or the Latin version "in re", so most of the translations are wrong. I personally find the translations unnecessary and ugly for precisely the reasons you state.

Comment: Note that RFC 5322 specifically states in section 3.6.5 that the informational fields (of which `Subject` is one) is *unstructured* as well as *optional*. Replies *MAY* (not *shall*) have a subject starting with `Re: `.

Answer (score 2):

One reason why this is common would be that many (most common?) e-mail clients on Windows *don't* do proper threading based on `Message-ID:`, `References:` and `In-Reply-To:`.

Proper threading also requires that the previous message in the thread is available; depending on the mail storage design, it may even need to be available in the same mailbox. On mailing lists (reflectors) this is a minor problem; for one-on-one conversations between individuals, it's a game-changer.

Having a visual cue in the subject line allows the user to see easily, at a glance, from a single entry in the list of emails, whether a message is an original message, a forward, a follow-up or reply, etc.

Forwarded messages commonly don't include any reference information; the MUA would have to go hunting through any mail message-parts, *assuming* that the mail is even forwarded as a MIME attachment and not simply copied by the MUA into the body of the new email.

Changing convention is a hard thing to do.

All of the above seem like good reasons to keep the tags in the subject line even if *technically* they *could* be omitted *in some cases.*

That said, I agree with you on the translation of those tags, which can create a mess. Not only can the recipient be unfamiliar with the tag the other person's software uses (I'd have no idea what `İLT` means, for example, let alone `תגובה` which I doubt I'd even recognize), but some combinations are outright ambiguous (Danish/Norwegian `VS:` and Finnish `VS:`, for example), greatly reducing the value of the subject line tag. [Wikipedia: List of email subject abbreviations in languages other than English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_%28e-mail%29#Abbreviations_in_other_languages).